# Normed Linear Spaces: Define homomorphism, homeomorphism, isomorphism, isometry

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I've spent several hours reading through several textbooks and online resources trying to understand the specific definitions and distinctions between these terms. Could someone help clarify this?

In the specific context of normed linear spaces and functional analysis, are the following definitions correct:

- **Homomorphism**: A homomorphism is a structure preserving map, which in a vector space, is equivalent to being a linear map.
- **Isomorphism**: (same as homeomorphism) A bijective map such that both it and its inverse are linear and continuous.
- **Homeomorphism**: same as isomorphism.
- **Isometry**: a map that preserves norms. So, if $T: X \to Y$ is an isometry among normed linear spaces, then ${\lVert Tx \rVert}_Y = {\lVert x \rVert}_X$

### Questions

- In the context of vector spaces and normed linear spaces, is a homomorphism equivalent to being linear in the sense that $T(\lambda a + b) = \lambda T(a) + T(b)$? A map is a homomorphism if and only if it is linear?
- Is an isomorphism equivalent to a homeomorphism in normed linear spaces?
- Wikipedia says [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) that "An isometry is an isomorphism of metric spaces." and "A homeomorphism is an isomorphism of topological spaces." This is confusing. A metric space is a topological space, with a topological basis being all metric balls. The Muscat textbook on functional analysis defines isomorphism as follows, which is what other resources define as a homeomorphism, except this requires linearity and linear inverses. [image: isomorphism] It seems that the meaning of an isomorphism depends on the context in which it is used?
- Are both isomorphisms and homeomorphisms required to be linear such that $T(\lambda a + b) = \lambda T(a) + T(b)$ and required to have linear inverses? The Wikipedia definition of homeomorphism doesn't specify anything about being linear and having a linear inverse. [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Homeomorphism)

Comment: Usually a homeomorphism is defined as a bijective continuous map, whose inverse is continuous as well. It doesn't have to be linear.

Answer (score 1):

"Isomorphism" is as quoted in the gray box **but including linearity** (and then the inverse is automatically also linear).  I hope the person writing that Wikipedia definition included linearity before that.

We would say "homeomorphism" for a bijection continuous in both directions, no connection with the linear structure.  Similarly "isometry" is $\|Tx - Ty\|_Y = \|x-y\|_X$, no requirement of linearity.   We can say "linear isometry" if we want both properties; and "linear bijective isometry" if we want the inverse to exist.  And "isomorphism" = "linear homeomorphism".

We do not say "homomorphism" at all ... For a continuous linear map (equivalently, bounded linear map) we may say "linear operator".  These can be the morphisms of a category; we often write $L(X,Y)$: the bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$; it can be given the structure of normed linear space in a standard way.

Another category used for normed spaces uses "contractive linear operators" as morphisms: that is, linear maps with $\|Tx\|_Y \le \|x\|_X$.  (The isomorphisms for this category are the linear bijective isometries.)